# Using SVN and Git side-by-side

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github, google-code

I'm using SVN and Git to version-control the same folder, and am committing to 2 separate repositories; one hosted on Google Code and the other on GitHub, respectively.

SVN creates `.svn` directories in every directory that it tracks. When I add my files and folders to Git, I use globbing and simply glob the folder that I've modified in my working copy because there are lots of files and subdirectories in it, and I don't want to add them one by one.

I've tried adding `*/.svn/*` to my `.gitignore` file, but to no avail. Is there any way of making Git and SVN coexist without the the clutter of SVN getting committed to the Git repo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you should need to do is add `.svn` to your `.gitignore` file, without the extra slashes and stars. Or better, add it to `.git/info/exclude` which serves the same purpose for your own use and doesn't get committed to your repository.

Comment: Will the `.svn` entry in the `.gitignore` file make sure that the `.svn` folders are ignored in every subdirectory?